# How do I output an embed of a private file PDF in views

Tags: views, 10

What I am trying to do is embed a pair of PDF files on a page using a View; however because they are uploaded to the private file store I think I am on to a loser.

My preferred desire is to have the PDF viewable on the page generated by the View, but that they can be clicked on and downloaded as well.

—

I am using Drupal 10

I have a content type where the user uploads two separate PDF’s into two separate ‘file’ entity slots. They are both saved a private rather than public files.

I have the view created (which is also restricted to the relevant roles) and have re-written the output for each one as

```
<object data="{{ field_[PDFname] }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
      <p>Unable to display PDF file. <a href="{{ field_[PDFname] }}">Download</a> instead.</p>
    </object>
```

No embed occurs though and each time it falls back to the download option, presumably as I overlooked that object is not a permitted html tag.

I have also tried *Embedded Google Docs Viewer* but it fails because the PDF is set to private and not public

I also tried to set up *Media PDF Thumbnail* to see if there was a way around, however I struggled to even get it set up? I tried to follow [the guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/media-pdf-thumbnail/usage-in-media-view-mode) on the Drupal Contributed Modules pages and could not even set up a media entity view mode (I am probably overlooking something obvious)

Is it possible to embed a PDF in this way? Is there a pdf viewer that would achieve this?